# DB2 - SQL filtering records from a subquery recordset

Tags: sql, filter, db2, subquery

First of all I am not very well versed in SQL.

I am trying to filter the result based on the records of a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTCINT 
    t.end_zone, l2.LS_TRIP_NUMBER, l2.LS_DRIVER, 
    l2.LS_POWER_UNIT, l2.LS_ACTUAL_DATE
FROM
    LYNX.LEGSUM l
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    LYNX.TLORDER t ON l.LS_DLID = t.DETAIL_LINE_ID
INNER JOIN 
    LYNX.LEGSUM l2 ON l2.LS_FROM_ZONE = t.END_ZONE
                   AND l2.LS_DRIVER = l.LS_DRIVER
                   AND l2.LS_POWER_UNIT = l.LS_POWER_UNIT
WHERE
    t.ORIGIN = 'PRO8060'
    AND l.LS_ACTUAL_DATE >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND l.LS_ACTUAL_DATE < '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND NOT (t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'CANCEL'
             OR t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'CANCL'
             OR t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'ENTRY')
```

Now, what I want to do is to filter from my Legsum (LS) table based the following:

```
-LS.Origin = t.endzone
-LS.Power_unit = l2.power_unit
-LS.Driver = l2.Driver
-LS.actual_date Between l.actual_date and DAY(l.actual_date)+1
```

Where I get stuck is when I try to get all those conditions on the result of my subquery, here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT
    LEGSUM.LS_TRIP_NUMBER, LEGSUM.LS_LEG_DIST, LS_MT_LOADED 
FROM
    LYNX.LEGSUM LEGSUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    LYNX.TLORDER TLORDER ON LEGSUM.LS_DLID = TLORDER.DETAIL_LINE_ID
WHERE
    LEGSUM.LS_ACTUAL_DATE >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND LEGSUM.LS_ACTUAL_DATE < '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND NOT (TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER LIKE 'A%'
             OR TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER LIKE 'C%'
             OR TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER LIKE 'L%'
             OR TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER LIKE 'Q%'
             OR TLORDER.BILL_NUMBER LIKE 'MA%')
    AND NOT (TLORDER.CURRENT_STATUS = 'CANCEL'
             OR TLORDER.CURRENT_STATUS = 'CANCL'
             OR TLORDER.CURRENT_STATUS = 'ENTRY')
    AND LEGSUM.LS_FROM_ZONE IN (SELECT DISTINCT t.end_zone, l2.LS_TRIP_NUMBER, l2.LS_DRIVER, l2.LS_POWER_UNIT
                                FROM LYNX.LEGSUM l
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN LYNX.TLORDER t ON l.LS_DLID = t.DETAIL_LINE_ID
                                INNER JOIN LYNX.LEGSUM l2 ON l2.LS_FROM_ZONE = t.END_ZONE
                                                          AND l2.LS_DRIVER = l.LS_DRIVER
                                                          AND l2.LS_POWER_UNIT = l.LS_POWER_UNIT
                                WHERE t.ORIGIN = 'PRO8060'
                                  AND l.LS_ACTUAL_DATE >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
                                  AND l.LS_ACTUAL_DATE < '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
                                  AND NOT (t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'CANCEL'
                                           OR t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'CANCL'
                                           OR t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'ENTRY')
                               )
```

This is getting the first condition but not the other 3

Thank you for any and all help

Answer (score 0):

Consider `EXISTS` instead of `IN` where you correlate subquery columns with outer query columns. See last 4 `WHERE` clause conditions in subquery to be modified as needed. This approach recommends use of table aliases in outer query for the correlations.

```
SELECT
    l.LS_TRIP_NUMBER, l.LS_LEG_DIST, l.LS_MT_LOADED 
FROM
    LYNX.LEGSUM l
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    LYNX.TLORDER t ON l.LS_DLID = t.DETAIL_LINE_ID
WHERE
    l.LS_ACTUAL_DATE >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND l.LS_ACTUAL_DATE < '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND NOT (t.BILL_NUMBER LIKE 'A%' OR t.BILL_NUMBER LIKE 'C%'
             OR t.BILL_NUMBER LIKE 'L%' OR t.BILL_NUMBER LIKE 'Q%'
             OR t.BILL_NUMBER LIKE 'MA%')
    AND NOT (t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'CANCEL'
             OR t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'CANCL'
             OR t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'ENTRY')
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM LYNX.LEGSUM sub_l
                LEFT OUTER JOIN LYNX.TLORDER sub_t ON sub_l.LS_DLID = sub_t.DETAIL_LINE_ID
                INNER JOIN LYNX.LEGSUM sub_l2 ON sub_l2.LS_FROM_ZONE = t.END_ZONE
                      AND sub_l2.LS_DRIVER = sub_l.LS_DRIVER
                      AND sub_l2.LS_POWER_UNIT = sub_l.LS_POWER_UNIT
                WHERE sub_t.ORIGIN = 'PRO8060'
                  AND sub_l.LS_ACTUAL_DATE >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
                  AND sub_l.LS_ACTUAL_DATE < '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
                  AND NOT (sub_t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'CANCEL'
                           OR sub_t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'CANCL'
                           OR sub_t.CURRENT_STATUS = 'ENTRY')

                  AND l.LS_FROM_ZONE = sub_t.endzone
                  AND l.LS_POWER_UNIT = sub_l2.LS_POWER_UNIT
                  AND l.LS_DRIVER = sub_l2.LS_DRIVER
                  AND l.LS_ACTUAL_DATE  BETWEEN sub_l.LS_ACTUAL_DATE  
                                            AND (sub_l.LS_ACTUAL_DATE  + 1 DAYS)
               )
```